How do I add an annotation to Highcharts line chart where series data was loaded from csv?
My goal is to pull chart data from a database and to also pull annotation data from a database.
The CSV chart data looks like this:
Timestamp,Flow,Temperature
2024-05-08 1:00:00,10,20
2024-05-08 2:00:00,12,15
2024-05-08 2:30:00,,16
2024-05-08 3:00:00,9,18
2024-05-08 4:00:00,7,19

My highchart example below correctly pulls and loads it from a csv file. The chart appears as I would expect.  The xAxis is of each data point on the chart is type "datetime" so it properly displays the time of the data point.
However, when trying to add an annotation to any given point, the xAxis appears to be using a Unix timestamp created from the CSV file but in GMT format.  If I locally create a new javascript date object for the same time as a data point on the chart and use .getTime() to get a Unix formatted value, it will return a value for the datetime but in my Local timezone.
For example: the chart loaded a data point at "2024-05-08 2:00:00" and used an xAxis value of "1715133600000".  But if you create a local date object for that same datetime, you get a value of "1715153400000"
In my case, the Unix timestamp is off by -5 hours  This value cannot be used to add the annotation to the chart because there are no data points on the xAxis on the chart for that time.
Is there a setting in HighCharts to build the xAxis values using the local time instead of GMT time?  Is there a work around?
[```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Highcharts Example</title>

<script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script src="js/highcharts11.js"></script>
<script src="js/data11.js"></script>
<script src="js/exporting11.js"></script>
<script src="js/accessibility11.js"></script>   
<script src="js/annotations11.js"></script>
<script src="js/export-data11.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="container" style="height: 400px; min-width: 380px"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
          $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
        });

            
        //Build the chart
        var thisChart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
            chart: {
                type: 'line'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Live Data (CSV)'
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: 'Data input from a remote CSV file'
            },
            xAxis: {
                type: 'datetime',
                title: { text: 'x axis title'}
            },              
            plotOptions: {
                series: { connectNulls: true ,
                    point: {
                        events: {
                            click: function () {       
                            alert("this.series.name = " + this.series.name + "\nthis.x = " + this.x + "\nthis.y = " + this.y);
                                    
                            } //click
                        } //events
                    } //point               
                }// series
            },          
            data: {
                csvURL: 'http://localhost/tundra/zdata.csv',
                enablePolling: false
            } //data                                            
        }); //thisChart
        
        // Try to add an annotation at 2:00:00
        //var date = new Date("2024-05-08 2:00:00 "); 
        var date = new Date("2024-05-07 21:00:00 "); 
        alert(date.getTime()); //1715151600000
                    
        var a2 = {
            labels: [{
                point: {
                    //x: 1715133600000, // this works but it is GMT time
                    x: date.getTime(), 
                     //1715151600000 --> GMT minus 5 hours
                    y: 15,
                    yAxis: 0,
                    xAxis:0                         
                },
                text: 'basic annotation'
            }],
            labelOptions: {
                borderRadius: 5,
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(252, 255, 197, 0.7)',
                borderWidth: 1,
                borderColor: '#AAA'
            },
        }
            
            thisChart.addAnnotation(a2);            
            
            //alert('done');
            
        </script>
    </body>
</html>




Could you reproduce this issue in an online editor I could work on? I'm not sure if this problem is related to Highcharts library or to the date issues. You can use this demo as a basic template: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/59mxnqj4/

Dominik thanks for looking.  I have updated the fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/Zordl/4mkf8qLt/11/

Sorry, but I'm afraid the issue is not strictly related to Highcharts. The charting library is working fine. The problem lies with the dates. You probably need to calculate the time offset you're receiving when transforming your date to a Unix timestamp. This thread might be helpful to you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14134396/calculating-javascript-date-time-with-offset
